# How to include a close button using jQuery toggle left to right?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I include a close button using jQuery UI toggle function?

```
$(".login").click(function () {

    $(this).hide();

    $("#myDiv").toggle("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 500);

});
```

[My jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/TX55G/204/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/TX55G/207/

```
$(".login, .close").click(function () {

    $('.login').toggle();

    $("#myDiv").toggle("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 500);

});
```

Show/Hide click button after toggle: http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/TX55G/208/

```
$(".login, .close").click(function () {

    $("#myDiv").toggle("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 500, function () { $('.login').toggle(); });

});
```

If you want to hide the click prior to showing close and show the click after hiding close you can do this. Although I will point out using the visible/hidden selectors can be bad on performance but I was attempting to not make many changes to your code. You can do this without using them easily.

http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/TX55G/209/

```
$(".login, .close").click(function () {

    var hiding = $('.login:visible');
    if (hiding.length == 1) {
        $('.login:visible').toggle();
    }

    $("#myDiv").toggle("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 500, function () {
        if (hiding.length == 0) {
            $('.login').toggle();
        }
    });

});
```

This is the way I would do it instead of using those special selectors. I would use a class. http://jsfiddle.net/AtheistP3ace/TX55G/211/

CSS:

```
.hide {
    display: none;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".login, .close").click(function () {

    var login = $('.login');
    var hiding = !login.hasClass('hide');
    if (hiding) {
        $('.login').addClass('hide');
    }

    $("#myDiv").toggle("slide", {
        direction: "left"
    }, 500, function () {
        if (!hiding) {
            $('.login').removeClass('hide');
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: Thank you. Is it possible to show the Click button after the toggle is done?

Comment: @brunodd added a new fiddle hiding click immediately and showing it only after close is hidden.

Comment: thank you. Almost there. Do you know how I can hide the Click button in order to show the content? - http://jsfiddle.net/brunodd/TX55G/210/

Comment: @brunodd take a look at what i just added to answer and let me know if thats what you want.

Comment: @brunodd no problem! Added one more thing to answer at bottom. What I think in my opinion is a better way to do it instead of using the visible selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".login, .close").click(function () {
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/TX55G/205/)**

Comment: Woow! That was so simple! I feel bad now =( Thank you @isherwood

Comment: To be fair, you may have to tweak it a bit to bring back the Click link and not hide the Close link. http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/TX55G/206/